# storing result of expect expression in variable

Tags: scripting, expect

I'm trying to store the length of a string variable in another variable. If I open an expect prompt and run `string length test`, I get 4. However, if I try `set len string length $var` I get:

```
wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"
    while executing
"set len string length $var"
```

I also tried `set len {string length $var}` but then the `len` variable simply contains the string `"string length $var"`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command substitution will happen only if you have enclosed them required commands within square brackets.

```
set var "CalumMcCall"
set len [string length $var]
```